# MATLAB: vectorize filling of 3D-array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I would like to safe a certain amount of grayscale-images (->2D-arrays) as layers in a 3D-array.
Because it should be very fast for a realtime-application I would like to vectorize the following code, where m is the number of shifts:

```
for i=1:m
  array(:,:,i)=imabsdiff(circshift(img1,[0 i-1]), img2);
end
```

nispio showed me a very advanced version, which you can see here:

```
I = speye(size(img1,2)); E = -1*I;
ii = toeplitz(1:m,[1,size(img1,2):-1:2]);
D = vertcat(repmat(I,1,m),E(:,ii));

data_c = shape(abs([double(img1),double(img2)]*D),size(data_r,1),size(data_r,2),m);
```

At the moment the results of both operations are not the same, maybe it shifts the image into the wrong direction. My knowledge is very limited, so I dont understand the code completely.

Comment: What are the dimensions of image? v is a vector, so image has to be rows x col x 20 in this case. Also I don't think you are using circshift correctly. The documentation says: "shiftsize is a vector of integer scalars where the n-th element specifies the shift amount for the n-th dimension of array A." So unless you have 20 dimensions  to image...

Comment: `[0 1:20]` in your case doesn't make sense. If `image` is a 2-D array then `[0 1]` and `[0 1:n]` (n is any number greater than 1) will give same result since you are rotating a singleton dimension. If you want to actually circularly shift the image to create new images and put them in 3-D arrays (I don't know what that operation means physically) then the solution below using for loops is correct.

Comment: In the end I want to have an array with 20 layers, where each layer contains a single image, and each image should be shifted by a different amount. So I need 20 different images at one array. I already did it with a for-loop, but it was to slow, I need it for stereo vision for realtime obstacle detection

Comment: Explain clearly what you want to store in layer 1, in layer 2 etc

Comment: Layer 1: Image shifted by 1, Layer 2: Image shifted by 2, Layer 3: Image shifted by 3 .. and so on

Comment: Your question is starting to make less sense as you edit it.  You say that you want to vectorize the code, and then you present my vectorized solution.  Please consider a more chronological presentation in which your give your original question, and then updates to explain any pieces that you feel are still unresolved.

Comment: I don't think that your `for` loop is doing what you think it is. Your  loop variable is `i`, but you never reference `i` in the loop itself, you reference `m` instead (which is a constant). Also notice that you never compare `img2` with the unshifted version of `img1` since the very first iteration of your loop shifts by `1` instead of `0`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: You are right, I updated the loop how it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
M = 16; N = 20; img1 = randi(255,M,N);       % Create a random M x N image
ii = toeplitz(1:N,circshift(fliplr(1:N)',1)); % Create an indexing variable

% Create layers that are shifted copies of the image
array = reshape(img1(:,ii),M,N,N);
```

As long as your image dimensions don't change, you only ever need to create the `ii` variable once.  After that, you can call the last line each time your image changes.  I don't know for sure that this will give you a speed advantage over a `for` loop, but it is vectorized like you requested. :)

## UPDATE

In light of the new information shared about the problem, this solution should give you an order of magnitudes increase in speed:

```
clear all;

% Set image sizes
M = 360; N = 500;

% Number of column shifts to test
ncols = 200;

% Create comparison matrix (see NOTE)
I = speye(N); E = -1*I;
ii = toeplitz([1:N],[1,N:-1:(N-ncols+2)]);
D = vertcat(repmat(I,1,ncols),E(:,ii));

% Generate some test images
img1 = randi(255,M,N);
img2 = randi(255,M,N);

% Compare images (vectorized)
data_c = reshape(abs([img2,img1]*D),M,N,ncols);

% Compare images (for loop)
array = zeros(M,N,ncols); % <-- Pre-allocate this array!
for i=1:ncols
  array(:,:,i)=imabsdiff(circshift(img1,[0 i-1]),img2);
end
```

This uses matrix multiplication to do the comparisons instead of generating a whole bunch of shifted copies of the image.

**NOTE:** The matrix `D` should only be generated *one time* if your image size is not changing.  Notice that the `D` matrix is completely independent of the images, so it would be wasteful to regenerate it every time. However, if the image size does change, you will need to update `D`.

**Edit:** I have updated the code to more closely match what you seem to be looking for.  Then I throw the "original" for-loop implementation in to show that they give the same result. One thing worth noting about the vectorized version is that it has the potential to be very memory instensive.  If `ncols = N` then the `D` matrix has `N^3` elements. Even though `D` is sparse, things fall apart fast when you multiply `D` by the non-sparse images.

Also, notice that I pre-allocate `array` before the `for` loop.  This is *always* good practice in Matlab, where practical, and it will almost invariably give you a large performance boost over the dynamic sizing.

Comment: I hate StackOverflow's syntax highlighting for Matlab.  There seems to be no rhyme or reason to it sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my problem is just that i have no idea how I can use the vector as an index for the 3D-array without getting the error.

Comment: @pixel  Perhaps you should update your question then, since my answer achieves exactly what your question asks for.

Comment: For some reason the 'image(:,ii)' has other dimensions than the original one, but I need to substract the shifted image later from an image of the size of an original one, otherwise I would also use your code.

Comment: `image (:, ii)` has the wrong dimensions *until* you reshape it.  Is that part not working as expected?

Comment: Yep, the problem was also that i missunderstood the 1:N inside of fliplr. Now I got it working, but it seems like it doesnt help to improve the performance alot. It looks like this         `ii=toeplitz(1:m,circshift(fliplr(1:size(img1,2))',1)); 
shiftarray = reshape(img1(:,ii),size(img1,1),size(img1,2),[]); imgarray=repmat(img2,[1 1 size(shiftarray,3)]);
data_c = imabsdiff(shiftarray, imgarray);`

Comment: @Pixel Using the new information you shared, I was able to increase the efficiency by almost 100-fold.  You can see that, in general, it is easier to optimize an entire process than it is to optimize individual steps of that process.

Comment: Thank you, that looks great, but I still get an error. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Pixel For images of size MxN, the D matrix must have the size (2N)x(N^2) for this to work.  If your image size changes, you need to update your D matrix as well.

Comment: Wow, it is really pretty fast. One last question: Does it also shift the second image? Because it should also shift the first one everytime and then it should substract the same second image every time. At the moment I get some strange results.

Comment: It actually doesn't shift either of the images. Creating multiple copies of the image is unnecessary if you are just making column comparisons.  It should achieve the exact same result, but faster because it is using sparse matrix multiplication instead of the copy/shift/subtract steps that you were using before.  I recommend that you write a `for` loop that does exactly what you want, and compare the output to verify that it is set up correctly.

Comment: I have udated my question with the original for-loop. At the moment both codes will end in different results. Your code shifts the image over the whole number of horizontal pixels,so I used my 'm' instand of the width of an image. Is that something that will Not work?

Comment: @Pixel Are you just looking to shift the image `1:m` pixels to the right, and `m` is *less than* the width of the image?

Comment: I updated the code yet again based on what I assume you mean by the variable `m`.  I have also added the `for` loop version for reference, to show that it yields the exact same result as the vectorized version.

Comment: Yes, `m` is a number that is smaller than the image.Thank you for the answer. Of the code gives the same result as the loop, it the question should be answered soon.

Comment: @Pixel I updated one more time to match the latest update to your question.

Comment: Now it is working perfectly. It increased the performance at a scale of 512*320p and 80 shifts, now it is more than ten times faster. Thanks a lot for your help and for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

If question is understood correctly, I think you need `for` loop

```
for v=1:1:20
  array(:,:,v)=circshift(image,[0 v]);
end
```